# tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I have a healthy file system, but I cannot run tune2fs on it:

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
tune2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Answer (score 6):

`tune2fs` is for ext file systems, and if this filesystem is healthy, then this filesystem cannot be an ext type filesystem (or it would have a super-block).

To check the type, use `blkid`.

e.g.

```
# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="6e264bd8-e7df-4003-b145-e65667361d65" TYPE="xfs"
```

For xfs file systems, instead of `tune2fs`, use `xfs_info`.

e.g.

```
# xfs_info  /dev/sda1
meta-data=/dev/sda1              isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=32000 blks
...
```